# Poll system multiple answers

Tags: php, mysql, database-design

If you would want to make a poll system that supports multiple answers (options) (not just yes/no) how would you do it? How would you structure the db etc?

I don't want to limit the answers/options.

Some input on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2070172/what-is-the-best-approach-to-store-question-data-into-a-database

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I used:

Pool table:

```
pool_id: int
pool_name: varchar
number_of_votes: int
```

Pool_question table:

```
question_id: int
pool_id: int
question: varchar
answer: varchar
question_selected_count: int
```

Comment: Or, you could do it with minor changes - with NO number_of_votes in pool (because number of votes in pool = SUM answer votes) and question in pool (because you have multiple answers for one question)